Why am I getting the error "APKs are not allowed for this application" when trying to submit an Android app to Google Play?
I'm trying to submit my app do Google Play, and after a succeded building, when I run eas build -p android I get the following error:
[logs] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application. - Retrying...
[logs] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application. - Retrying...
[logs] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application. - Retrying...
[logs] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application. - Retrying...
[logs] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application. - Retrying...
[logs] [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application.
[logs] Fastlane supply failed
[logs] Failed to submit the app to the store
[logs] End phase: SUBMIT_TO_PLAY_STORE

I've cleaned my eas.json file and I'm focusing only in the production env, so it is like this:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {},
    "preview": {},
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      }
    }
  }
}


I have no idea about what to do to force the .aab build format to update my app.
Tried to:

Change the eas.json
Clean caches
Delete android folder and rebuilding again to see if .aab is generated

Expecting to generade .aab to send in the eas submit command.

It was just one property to make eas build -p android generate aab, the applicationArchivePath:
    "build": {
    "development": {},
    "preview": {},
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "applicationArchivePath": "android/app/build/outputs/**/*.aab"
      }
    }
  }

